# upload local image on Pinterest

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinterest

i am able to upload photo that is on web to the pinterest with this code

```
 NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"];

  [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL
                       sourceURL:sourceURL
                     description:@"Pinning Demo"];
```

but i am not been able to find a way to upload local image to Pinterst.I dont want to put my local image on server first just want to local to pinterst,if is there any way please help

Comment: Have you tried with application document folder url?

Comment: i have tried this     imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    URLForResource: @"_default" withExtension:@"png"];

Comment: Plz try with an document folder image and then let me know?

Comment: yes,i read the docs of Pinterest for iOS.uploadong local image is not possible,we have to upload on server first

Comment: Kindly share the link and close the question.

Comment: With the launch of Pinterest version 2.3 for iOS, we'll be supporting the Pin It button SDK for your iOS app. This SDK will let your users create Pinterest content inside your app with just a few lines of code. Right now, we only support adding an image from a URL. In the future, we’ll support adding local images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this update Shehbaz.