# Share UIImage on pinterest iPhone development

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, pinterest

i am currently working on project that uses pinterest to share images. 
the problem is that pinterest API provides the following method :

```
[_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com/500/400"]
                        sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"]
                      description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
```

In my case, the images are located in my resource or i create them programmatically (NOT URL) .. how can i solve this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried writing the `UIImage` to a file and then constructing an `NSURL` pointing to the local path?

Comment: you can't upload images with the pinterest ios sdk .. you can only add pins to images that are already on a server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542665/upload-local-image-on-pinterest

Comment: thanx guys..yes i think i will wait Pinterest till they update their SDK.. appreciate your help